# how to add styles for content dialog title and button using c# for UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

```
ContentDialog Dialog = new ContentDialog();
private async void DisplaySessionDialog()
{
    var bStyle = new Style(typeof(Button));
    bStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)));
    bStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Maroon)));
    bStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
    bStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.VerticalContentAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center));
    bStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(15)));
    bStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(5)));
    bStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.MarginProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
    bStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.FontSizeProperty, 18));
    Dialog.Title = val.SessionExpireTitle;
    Dialog.Content = val.SessionExpireContent;
    Dialog.PrimaryButtonText = val.SessionExpireButtonLabel;
    Dialog.PrimaryButtonStyle = bStyle;
    Dialog.FontSize = 18;

    await Dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

The above code is working fine. However, I want to alignment button as a centre and title alignment centre, content also from left. I tried more ways and search a lot of things I did not find any solutions . Please help me, is there any way to align title in c# for UWP app

Comment: From a style, using XAML code is more efficient. Do you accept XAML?

Comment: my code in c#.Some specification i wrote code in c#

Comment: If you want to center the title of the Dialog, you need to modify the `ContentDialog.TitleTemplate`, which is a `DataTemplate` that is difficult to create with C# code. I even recommend that you create a `ContentDialog` (template) and put UI-related code in it (using XAML + C#). If you accept, I can provide a solution.